# Using the step and shift theorems to find the Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

**The Problem**

> $$f(t):=\begin{cases}e^{-t}&t\lt4\\e^{-2t}&4\le t\le10\\0&t\gt10\end{cases}$$

**What I know**
I can write this as one function:

$$f(t)= e^{-t} + (e^{-2t} - e^{-t})u(t-4) + (0 - e^{-2t})u(t-10)$$

and the Laplace property of:

$$g(t)u(t-a) = e^{-as}L(g(t+a))(s) $$

**Question**
Which property can I use for this transformation?

Comment: Use the linearity property of the Laplace transform, then apply the property already you have at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are asked to use some properties, you can work out the problem from scratch as

> $$ \int_{0}^{4} \dots e^{-st}\, dt + \int_{4}^{10} \dots e^{-st}\, dt +  \int_{10}^{\infty}\dots e^{-st}\, dt .$$

Now, plug in the right integrands in the above