# Laplace transform - Heaviside algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, laplace-transform

I'm strugling with some algebra around a laplace transform with heaviside. The start function is

$L(2tH(1-t)) + L(2H(t-1))$

so from this, I'm supposed to convert it to

$L(2t) + L(2(1-t)H(t-1))$

From that I understand how you continue, but dont see how they get there.

PS: First question ever, so how important is it to write the math with code? I feel I'm getting the point through, even without coding it :)

PSS: The assignment is 6e on this link 
[Where I have it from](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4123/2014v/excer6.pdf)!
if someone wants.

Maybe if someone could explain why

$L(f(t)u(a-t)) = L(f(t) - u(t-a)f(t))$

some light would be shed on the first question :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! In response to the "extra question": While it is always easy for you to understand what you have written, it is not always easy for others. And, it also looks better and emphasizes if the mathematics is written with MathJax (as it now has been edited to.)

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600950/using-the-step-and-shift-theorems-to-find-the-laplace-transform).

Comment: Didn't help me much, Mhenni :/ Been strugling a good hour to understand how they come up with this solution.